# MYSQL - Subquery returns more than 1 row - how to duplicate row with same userId?

Tags: mysql

Here is my subQuery, I cannot understand the error : 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id as userId,  
  (
                SELECT a10.description 
                FROM Export exp 
                INNER JOIN Account a10 ON (a10.id = exp.accountId)
                WHERE exp.isActive = 1 
                AND exp.platformId = 14
            ) as structur
            FROM User u
            LEFT JOIN AccountUser au ON au.userId = u.id and au.isDefault = 1
            LEFT JOIN Account a ON a.id = au.accountId
            WHERE u.id > 0
            ORDER BY u.id ASC
            LIMIT 10
```

ERROR : 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id as userId,  
  (
                SELECT a10.description 
                FROM Export exp
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery return more than a row  but a row cell accept just one value so if you really need  this subquery then you should limit the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id as userId,  
  (
                SELECT a10.description 
                FROM Export exp 
                INNER JOIN Account a10 ON (a10.id = exp.accountId)
                WHERE exp.isActive = 1 
                AND exp.platformId = 14
                LIMIT 1
            ) as structur
            FROM User u
            LEFT JOIN AccountUser au ON au.userId = u.id and au.isDefault = 1
            LEFT JOIN Account a ON a.id = au.accountId
            WHERE u.id > 0
            ORDER BY u.id ASC
            LIMIT 10
```

but looking to your code you could also avoid the subquery adding the join at the main query

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id as userId,  Account.description structur
    FROM User u
    LEFT JOIN AccountUser au ON au.userId = u.id and au.isDefault = 1
    LEFT JOIN Account a ON a.id = au.accountId
    LEFT JOIN exp ON ON Account.id = exp.accountId
        AND exp.isActive = 1 
        AND exp.platformId = 14
    WHERE u.id > 0
    ORDER BY u.id ASC
    LIMIT 10
```